# CXF auto generation fails with "Duplicated option: frontend" in maven?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, cxf

I have set up a simple cxf maven auto generation from a `WSDL` file. But I get the following exception. What am I missing?

> Execution generate-sources of goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.0:wsdl2java failed:
>   org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.parser.BadUsageException:
>   Duplicated option: frontend 
>   (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.0:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources)

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>

                    <configuration>
                      <defaultOptions>
                          <extraargs>
                              <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                              <extraarg>cxf</extraarg> 
                          </extraargs>
                      </defaultOptions>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/MyService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <wsdlLocation>classpath:/MyService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>


                 </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
 <dependencies>
```

Maven debug shows the following:

> [DEBUG] Calling wsdl2java with args: [-encoding, UTF-8, -d,
>   \target\generated\src\main\java, -fe, cxf, -fe, cxf, -wsdlLocation,
>   classpath:wsdl/MyService.wsdl,...

Why is the frontent `-fe` created twice??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove that `<extraargs><extraarg>-fe</extraarg><extraarg>cxf</extraarg></extraargs>` section.

Add this extraarg in wsdlOption

```
<wsdlOption>
    <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
</wsdlOption>
```

Comment: Great, it works a `wsdlOption` level. But why doesn't it work at `defaultOptions` level, which is exactly the intention for this to simple define the extraargs and reuse it for every `wsdl`?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the exact same problem. You have to disable the directory scan. Then you can keep the extraargs in the default options and don't have to repeat them for all the wsdlOptions.

```
      <configuration>
          <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
          <disableDirectoryScan>true</disableDirectoryScan>
          <defaultOptions>
            <extraargs>
              <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
              <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
              <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
              <extraarg>-suppress-generated-date</extraarg>
            </extraargs>
          </defaultOptions>
          <!--wsdlOptions--> 
      </configuration>
```